# SFDX Can query Package Installation Status, can we?

Tags: api, package-install

With SFDX we can run the install:report command to check the status of a package installation.

Is it possible to do the same via any API exposed by salesforce?

So my question: Where is there any documentation on how to query the installation status of a package via the Metadata or tooling API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tooling object for same for that named "packageinstallrequest" .

You can query status field to know the install request status

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_packageinstallrequest.htm

Update

Further research revealed that this tooling object tracks install and upgrade only of tooling API is used for package install .

Comment: well now i feel silly lol...thank you

Comment: Nps. Happens to me all the time

Comment: Seems this is not really working as expected. The results do not reflect what is currently happening...There are 3 packages that I installed and only 1 record coming back in these results. Not sure what is going on :(

Comment: Support case probably ? If this does not work I cannot imagine any other way sfdc cli does it ?

Comment: I have been playing install, upgrade, etc in the org and the only record returned is the install of one package from 4 days ago....support case in pointless unfortunately. Guess I am going to have to create a custom object and my own work around to store the state of an install...Lots of platform bugs in SF lately :( - Thanks for confirming that this is indeed the only way to go about this from an API perspective...

Comment: I would raise a bug still .This will at least be known issue. Agree on platform bugs lately .

Comment: Looks like this Table only updates when a Package is installed using this Table. Metadata API requests to install a package do not show up here....When a package is installed via the tooling API using a POST they do show up...

Comment: That's weird that API type matters .Thanks for sharing it back

Comment: Yea. I do not know if it is expected to work this way but I tried on a fresh org and this is what I found. No entry when installing via metadata api, but an entry did get created when installing via tooling api

Comment: Does metadata api give you any ID back ? We could use that ID to see which table it logs this request against ?

Comment: No. I was doing is synchronously so no ID was given. If it did not complete in 2 minutes the request returned the "taking a long time to install" error. Tooling seems to do Async....

Comment: I thought in metadata api also there is a way to force it to go async

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I am getting below error while querying using tooling api. errorCode: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY  , My SOQL is :  Select  Status, Errors, CreatedDate from PackageInstallRequest . tried in workbench as well using GET.